# Firebase Search not automatically updated until i turn off screen and turn it back on

Tags: java, android, firebase, searchview

i get really confused, why my search bar is not automatically displaying the result, it will display the result after im turn off the screen and turn it back on. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poicz.png)

here's my code :

```
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_guru);

        fotoGuru = findViewById(R.id.fotoguru);
        inputsearch = findViewById(R.id.input_search_bar);
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        arrayList = new ArrayList<DataSetGuru>();
        pengajarReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Pengajar");
//        pengajarReference.keepSynced(true);

        LoadListGuru("");

        inputsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (s.toString()!=null)
                {
                    LoadListGuru(s.toString());
                }
                else
                {
                    LoadListGuru("");
                }

            }
        });


    }

    private void LoadListGuru(String data) {
        Query query = pengajarReference.orderByChild("kategori").startAt(data).endAt(data+"\uf8ff");
        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<DataSetGuru>().setQuery(query,DataSetGuru.class).build();
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataSetGuru, FirebaseViewHolder>(options) {
```

im wondering how can i get this right? or what am i doing wrong from this code

Answer (score 0):

Do upload your adapter code too.
I think you forgot to add this line:
notifyDataSetChanged()